# Не работает эмулятор в Android Studio

Tags: android, эмулятор

Моя проблема в следующем. Пишу простое приложение - клиентскую часть интернет магазина. Пока что описано 2 layout: MainActivity и Toolbar. В mainActivity.java тоже пока что простенький код, который можно посмотреть можно на https://github.com/Pir-Anya/myshop :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initToolbar();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    }


}
```

У меня в Android SDK установлены следующие версии: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в Android Studio 2.2 установлен genymotion и в нем установлен девайс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска этого устройства в genymotion получаю следующую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже очень странно что на экране ничего нет, ни кнопок ни меню, хотя раньше  когда я пользовалась встроенным эмулятором в Eclipse все это было.
После деплоя своего простенького приложения на запущенное устройство в genymotion получается что экран не изменяется никак, но в логах студии вот что пишет:

```
06/30 13:57:47: Launching app
$ adb push C:\java\MyShop\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.testshop.myshop
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.testshop.myshop"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.testshop.myshop/com.testshop.myshop.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 1757 on device genymotion-google_nexus_5x___7_0_0___api_24___1080x1920-192.168.89.101:5555
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.testshop.myshop-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.testshop.myshop, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.testshop.myshop-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

          [ 06-30 06:58:12.863  1757: 1778 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebd0e7b0, tid 1778
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
I/Choreographer: Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Откуда берется это сообщение " Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."? Ведь мое приложение слишком простое. И этом ли дело или в эмуляторе? Помогите плиз кто сталкивался с таким.
P.S: пробовала встроенный эмулятор студии но с ним тоже не пошло.

Comment: родной эмулятор студии не пробовали использовать?

Comment: rjhdby, пробовала, Nexus 5 API 24. Тоже проблемы, долго грузился, потом вроде показалось что-то похожее на мое приложение, потом белый экран. В логах нет уже записи про 303 фрейма, но есть это 
"Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable."
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=E:\android-devices
Этот путь у меня в переменных среды прописан и папка эта есть.

Comment: Думаю что сообщение про 303 фрейма врятли связано с моим кодом, а скорее глюк genymotion

Comment: Мб что-то в layout. Похоже на то, что эмулятор не может отобразить элемент интерфейса и из-за этого сбои.